# Sorting a 2d array of Objects in Java (java.lang.Object)

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, arraylist

I have an ArrayList:

```
ArrayList<Object[][]> parents;
```

Where column 1 contains an ArrayList of Integers and column 2 contains a single int. I have cased parents as an ArrayList of Objects as the two objects inside it derive from Class Objects, rather than converting.

This is where I've gotten a problem, now I need to sort parents by column two, the ints, but have ran into the issue with using java.util.Arrays.sort as I get the following error:

```
The method sort(T[], Comparator<? super T>) in the type Arrays is not applicable for the arguments (ArrayList<Object[][]>, new Comparator<Integer[]>(){})
```

is there any way around this to cast that second column as an Integer? The error us coming from the ArrayList containing the more general Object

If this isn't possible, what is the best way to go about changing in the code so the array can be sorted?

Please don't mark as duplicate from the sorting of int[][] questions as I haven't seen this issue on here before.

Thank you!

EDIT - as requested this is an example of my ArrayList

```
[50, 50, 50, 100, 50, 80, 50], 925
[80, 100, 100, 50, 80, 100], 1300
[50, 100, 100, 50, 100, 100], 1200
```

Ignoring the first column, I'd like to sort it by the second, like so:

```
[50, 50, 50, 100, 50, 80, 50], 925
[50, 100, 100, 50, 100, 100], 1200
[80, 100, 100, 50, 80, 100], 1200
```

For context the first column is an array referencing items a player has in a game, and the second column is their cost (smaller is better). I'd like to sort the players by this cost column (2), and of course their items will move with them to the same sorted row. The results are sorted smallest first, so in a tournament selection (this is a genetic algorithm), I can 'kill' the players with the highest costs by trimming the ArrayList.

Comment: Please add a concrete example of the input and the desired output

Comment: You're doing it wrong. Use classes. Define a class Parent with a field of type List<Something> and a field of type int. Then use a List<Parent>, and sort them using a Comparator<Parent>. Java is an OO language. Use classes and objects.

Comment: What @JB Nizet said. Besides, the error message says the program expects an array and a comparator and the comparator should be able to compare the objects held by the array. Instead you are passing an `ArrayList` (which is NOT an array) and a comparator of type `Integer[]`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, this is not really the right way to do this. As @JB Nizet mentioned in the comments, you should create a class with appropriate members and then create a `List` of that class. The elements of those lists then can be compared in a safe way.

But if you should do it this way, here is a solution:

```
parents.sort(new Comparator<Object[][]>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(Object[][] o1, Object[][] o2) {
                return Integer.compare((int) o1[0][1], (int)o2[0][1]);
            }
        });
```

The error message you have reported is actually directing you to create a comparator which is compatible with the object being passed to `sort`.

This is not safe at all. The objects need to exactly have the format you have indicated they would have, otherwise all hell will break loose. Of course, you can add checks to the overriden compare method to ensure format is correct. But why burden yourself with all that complexity when you can use simple OO design patterns and have a nice meaningful class to solve your problem?